# How to validate react prop that should accept Component

Tags: reactjs, react-proptypes

Let's say I want my component to accept a property of type `React.Component`

```
const MyComponent = ({ child: Child }) => 
  <div>
    <Child {...childProps} />
  </div>

MyComponent.propTypes = {
  child: PropTypes.[???].isRequired
}
```

Is there any `React.Component` validator in `prop-types` that I can use ?

> **edit:** I've tried with `PropTypes.element`, but I get an error
> `Failed prop type: Invalid prop 'el' of type 'function' supplied to 'Test', expected a single ReactElement.`
>
> https://codesandbox.io/s/qk0jyq13yj
>
> **edit2:** I've just found in [material-ui they have custom validation](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/packages/material-ui-utils/src/componentPropType.js)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `element` property

```
MyComponent.propTypes = {
  child: PropTypes.element.isRequired
}
```

or `instanceOf`

```
MyComponent.propTypes = {
  child: PropTypes.instanceOf(ReactComponentName).isRequired
}
```

Comment: I've tried with `.element`, but it appears to be validating elements, not components and I want my component to be flexible and accept any valid React.Component and render it with the corresponding props